# Best practices against mass surveillance for everday internet usage?

Tags: privacy, anonymity, internet, surveillance

Corporations and governments use a variety of de-anonymization techniques to identify and profile users.

All aspects of our personal lives are now consolidated online (banking, medical, academic, remote work, shopping, dating, messaging, social media, news etc). This can reveal a lot of personal information like who you talk to, what you say, your medical conditions, your political opinions and so on.

In this day and age it's impossible to function in society without having some sort of online presence. So what can we do to minimize this data collection and maintain our privacy against mass surveillance efforts?

Comment: There is an excellent book on this subject - 'Data and Goliath', by Bruce Schneier.  You might want to give it a read.

Comment: The question is too broad and it is opinion based. I suggest to close it.